# Unittest mock patch fails randomly within loop

Tags: python, python-3.x, mocking, python-unittest

Can't provide much context given the complexity, but I'm hoping for some insight/thought-provoking questions as to why this is happening.

I'm testing a process which loads files into a database, so I'm patching the credentials for a database connection using `unittest.mock.patch` to use test and not production credentials. We have a series of mocks that are applied as a `contextmanager`, simplified version here:

```
from contextlib import ExitStack

def context_stack(contexts):
    stack = ExitStack()
    for context in contexts:
        stack.enter_context(context)
    return stack

def patch_mocks():
    mocks = [
        patch('db_config.ReadWrite', db_mocks.ReadWrite),
        patch('db_config.ReadWrite', db_mocks.ReadWrite)
    ]
    return context_stack(mocks)
```

It gets used as such (simplified):

```
with patch_mocks():
    LoadFiles(file_list)
```

`LoadFiles` will iterate over each file in `file_list` and attempt to insert the contents into the database. The underlying methods connect to the database using `db_config.ReadWrite` but of course they are patched by `db_mocks.ReadWrite`. This works pretty consistently except, seemingly very randomly, it will fail as it tries to instead use `db_config.ReadWrite` when trying to create the connection.

So for example, there could be a hundred files, and it will patch the most of them successfully, but it will randomly stop using the patch halfway through and fail the test. What conditions/variables could be causing this patch to not be applied? Is there a limit to the number of patches that can be applied? Should it be applied in another way?

Comment: Without possibility to reproduce, I could only suggest using pdb. Add a breakpoint at the beginning of real `db_config.ReadWrite` and print call stack once it's hit. You could then analyze where does this call come from. Maybe the method is being called from somewhere else? Assuming you have to patch the right namespace...

Answer (score 1):

My first line of investigation would involve this warning from [the docs on .patch()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#patch):

> target should be a string in the form 'package.module.ClassName'. The target is imported and the specified object replaced with the new object, so the target must be importable from the environment you are calling patch() from. **The target is imported when the decorated function is executed, not at decoration time.**

and this further explanation on [Where to patch](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#where-to-patch)

> The basic principle is that you patch where an object is looked up, which is not necessarily the same place as where it is defined.

I would try to find a broken case and check the status of the import environment there to make sure the same import you're using everywhere else is reachable from there.

Answer (score 0):

Do not patch/mock, instead use the [repository pattern](https://www.martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/repository.html) to access the database.

You would then have two implementations of the Repository interface:

- in memory: keeps all data in-memory
- using a DB-driver/connector: actually writes to the DB